# Why does this code give a run time error on some specific test cases (which i cannot think of)

Tags: python, runtime-error

Forgive me if the code is messy and huge !'_'
I was trying to solve a codeforces problem, please ignore the logic as of now

```
def base_factorize(n, base_factors):
  factors = []

  if (n%base_factors[0]!=0 and n%base_factors[1]!=0):
      return factors
  if(n%base_factors[0]==0 and n%base_factors[1]!=0):
      while(n%base_factors[0]==0):
          n//=base_factors[0]
          factors.append(base_factors[0])
      if(n!=1):
          factors.append(n)
      # factors.append(1)
      return factors
  if(n%base_factors[1]==0 and n%base_factors[0]!=0):
      while(n%base_factors[1]==0):
          n//=base_factors[1]
          factors.append(base_factors[1])
      if(n!=1):
          factors.append(n)
      # factors.append(1)
      return factors
  if(n//base_factors[0]==1):
      # print(base_factors[0]," divides n")
      factors.append(base_factors[0])
      # factors.append(1)

  if(n//base_factors[1]==1):
      factors.append(base_factors[1])
      # factors.append(1)
  for fact in factors:
      if fact in base_factors:
        base_factors.remove(fact)



  start_factor = max(base_factors)
  other_fac=min(base_factors)
  while n%start_factor==0:
      n//=start_factor
      factors.append(start_factor)
  while n%other_fac==0:
      n//=other_fac
      factors.append(other_fac)
  if n!=1:
      factors.append(n)
  factors.append(1)



  return factors







for t in range(int(input())):


    a,b,n=map(int,input().split())
    if(a==1 and b==1 and n==1):
        print(1)
        continue
    Case='0' if n//a!=1 and n//b!=1 else '1'

    mul,ta,tb=0,0,0

    factors=base_factorize(n,[a,b])
    # print(f"a:{a} b:{b} n: {n} :",factors)
    ct=0
    if factors==0 or factors==None or factors==[]:
        print (1)
        continue
    if 1 not in factors:
        factors.append(1)
    for item in factors:
        if item==a:
            ta+=1
        elif item==b:
            tb+=1
        else:
            ct+=1
    if(Case=='1' or ta==0 or tb==0 and a!=b):
        ct-=1
    for i in range(0,ta+1):

        for j in range(0,tb+1):
            # print("product: ",a**i*b**j, " ",a**i*b**j<=n)
            if(a**i*b**j<=n and a**i*b**j!=1 ):
                mul+=1
    # print(ct)
    if(mul+ct!=0 and mul+ct!=-1):


        print(mul+ct)
    else:
        print(1)
```

This is the code. The base_factorization method takes n, [a,b] to try and factorize n in various cases. It works fine for many test cases but for some test cases which i cannot see it gives runtime error.

I am guessing the issue is due to something in the base_factorization method but I cannot figure out what. The list indices cannot be out of range so idk what's causing it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word **traceback**. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Comment: It's easy to force an error. Imagine what happens if you call the function and the value of both parameters is `None`.

Comment: @Matthias it wont happen since the code is for a coding website where there are certain constraints which will never be violated. So no parameters can be none